# Is it possible to use search queries in the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, search

Is it possible to use search queries in the iOS app?

For example, what would be the equivilient for the following?

```
[*worklight*] or [*mobilefirst*] is:question answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no
```

I suppose what I'm leading to is that I thought there would be some "query builder UI" in the app to create these much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mobile apps support the *exact same search syntax* as the full site does. You can copy and paste your sample query into the search box and it'll Just Work.

You do have to type in the query manually; there is no query builder (but neither is there one on the full site).

Comment: True, but on the desktop website, typing it is much faster whereas in the app on could argue a 'builder' might be faster...